# Find a highest density interval with fixed width

Tags: python, probability-density

**Problem**
Assuming independent random variable X are integer and follow gamma distribution, with a = 100, location = 0, scale = 1.
The output has to be an interval with fixed width 10 for X (covering 10 numbers), E.g. I can output [96, 105], etc. The starting point and ending point of the interval must be integer. And the interval needs to cover as most probability of X's distribution as possible.

**Current solution**
I'm using forloop(python) like this:

```
import scipy.stats.gamma as gamma

X_with_peak_density = 100
available_spots_in_interval = 9 # X_with_peak_density takes one space in the interval
X_new_left = X_with_peak_density
X_new_right = X_with_peak_density

for i in range(available_spots_in_interval):
    left = gamma.pdf(X_new_left - 1, a = 100, loc = 0, scale = 1)
    right = gamma.pdf(X_new_right + 1, a = 100, loc = 0, scale = 1)
    if left >= right:
        X_new_left = X_new_left - 1
    else:
        X_new_right = X_new_right + 1

res = (X_new_left, X_new_right)
```

This is kinda slow since it runs forloop in python. Is there any built solution more efficient?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact although brute-force way:

```py
n = available_spots_in_interval + 1
x = gamma.cdf(np.linspace(0, 200, 201), a=100, loc=0, scale=1)
X_new_right = np.argmax(x[n:] - x[:-n]) + n
```

It's computing the CDF and finding the place where the CDF has the biggest jump over 10 samples.

The drawback is this involves computing the CDF at lots of points, at least enough to be sure you have bracketed the correct answer, so it might not be faster.  If you increase the first argument to `np.linspace` (to compute fewer points), then you'll need to add that to `X_new_right`.  The number of points should be `end - start + 1` to ensure integer sample points.